# Find and Delete Empty Directories

Tags: command-line, nautilus, directory

How to Find Folders (Directories) That are empty (Not Containing Any Files) and Delete Them
By Using Terminal Command or Another Method.

Filtration (Finding Directories or Files) Less than 'N' bytes not Safe Because There are files which is only of 50 bytes but should be kept.

I Want to Find only Empty (sub)Directories in Prticular Folder.

Comment: Huh… I was halfway through an answer. Note that if you have nested directories, you will have to run the command multiple times, since the higher directory will not be empty until the lower directory is removed.